# python transfer parameter to function

Tags: python, class, parameters

I have one class that looks so:

```
class RSA:
 def encode(self,gui): 
    print "decoding started"
```

I want to call encode function from another class, when button, which is located in another class, is pressed. I can do it fine, if encode function has only one parameter - self.  
I do it so:

```
Class GUI:
 self.parameter=8 # parameter which I want to pass
 def method(self):
  encode = Button(frame,command=rsa.encode)
```

And it works fine (if encode function has only one default parameter -self).

But I need to pass yet one parameter to the function rsa.encode. If I try to pass it  so :

`self.encode = Button(frame,command=rsa.encode (self.parameter) )`
  - It will be called once and immediately, when interpreter reaches  this line and never again.

But it's not what I want, I want  it to be called only when button is pressed. It could be easily done in C++, but here, I wonder that it's not work as there.

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an [anonymous function](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms) to create a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29):

```
self.encode = Button(frame,command=lambda : rsa.encode (self.parameter) )
```

Comment: Just asking (not sure myself): Will `self.parameter` be evaluated only once when the button is created, or each time when it is clicked?

Comment: @tobias_k -- It will be looked up/evaluated (if it's a property) each time the button is clicked.